# Java TreeMap : Unable to sort the TreeMap key in decreasing order of the length/value

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap, treemap

I am trying to use the `TreeMap` to sort my keys, which are being stored in the `Map<String,Integer>`. But for some reason, the keys are not arranged correctly in decreasing order, as intended. I would like to know if there is a default way to achieve the intended order of the keys or I need to write some custom method to achieve this?

Following is the sample code I have:

```
public class ApplicationMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<String, Integer> sampleTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        sampleTreeMap.put("5903766131", 6);
        sampleTreeMap.put("5903767", 7);
        sampleTreeMap.put("590376614", 5);
        sampleTreeMap.put("5903766170", 9);
        sampleTreeMap.put("59037662", 12);
        sampleTreeMap.put("5903766410", 10);

        sampleTreeMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry ->{
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " -- " + entry.getValue());
        });
    }
}
```

The following is the output I am getting:

```
Key : 5903766131 -- 6
Key : 590376614 -- 5
Key : 5903766170 -- 9
Key : 59037662 -- 12
Key : 5903766410 -- 10
Key : 5903767 -- 7
```

I would like the output to be in descending order of the keys, so a larger number with a higher number of digits or characters would appear at the top, then a lower number with fewer digits. Something like this:

```
Key : 5903766410 -- 10
Key : 5903766170 -- 9
Key : 5903766131 -- 6
Key : 590376614 -- 5
Key : 59037662 -- 12
Key : 5903767 -- 7
```

Note:

1. I cannot change my data type to Integer or Long as this is coming from another application, and I would like to use it as a string in further processing, so I would like to find a way in which I can sort them properly.
2. I was previously using HashMap, but after discovering that it does not support ordering, I switched to TreeMap.

Please provide some suggestions on how to fix the issue.

Comment: The following solution also worked for me so providing the answer as it can be helpful to someone in the future: `final Map<String, Integer> sampleTreeMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder((a, b) -> a.length() != b.length() ? Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()) : a.compareTo(b)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to sort the keys as numbers instead of strings. One way to do this is to provide a custom `Сomparator` when creating the map.

```
final Map<String, Integer> sampleTreeMap =
                new TreeMap<>((Comparator.comparingLong((String s) -> Long.parseLong(s))).reversed());
```

P.S.
You might find it helpful to read this question
[Comparator .comparing().reversed() strange behaviour / not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500400/comparator-comparing-reversed-strange-behaviour-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. This worked fine in the sample question provided above but when I tried with the actual data in my application some of the entries were not sorting properly for some reason. I changed a bit and trued this `Collections.reverseOrder((a, b) -> a.length() != b.length() ? Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()) : a.compareTo(b))` and it worked as expected.

Comment: `Map<String, Integer> sampleTreeMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder( Comparator.comparingLong(Long::parseLong)));` should do as well.

Comment: @Holger may be not as well when comparing "123" and "0123" for example. I believe that the questioner got the problem with a similar situation.

Comment: @chptr-one my variant does exactly the same as yours.